# Counting how many times a total value goes over/under

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have ran into a hiccup and am lost.

I am trying to retrieve how many times the Away team’s games have gone over in the last 5.

In the sheet named “lines” I want to look up B3’s team name in sheet “DB” where B3 matches column B or D and obviously the total would be the value in the row from C and E. The DB games are listed where the most recent game is the last in the DB sheet.  the total I need to compare to is the Vegas Total in lines sheet cell AB3

I plan on manually making a matrix to fix the mismatched names as I pull new Vegas lines.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hI-b9LwFIXCvO8OyetgZUIimHBoUygTaNoWpSAHzUHU/edit?usp=sharing

This is also the formula i was trying `=COUNTIF(QUERY(DB!B:Z, "SELECT C, E WHERE B = '"&B3&"' ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 5"), ">"&K3)`

Any help would be appreciated.

These would be the last 5 Totals for Liberty(B3 from lines)

161
132
149
162
130

144 is the vegas total. so for AE I just want it to say "3" since that's how many times Liberty's last 5 games have gone over 144.

Comment: Can you provide us the ideal expected value in AE3 (**by calculating it manually**) with an added explanation of how you arrived at that specific value?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow
These would be the last 5 Totals for Liberty(B3 from lines) 

161
132
149
162
130

144 is the vegas total. so for AE I just want it to say "3" since that's how many times Liberty's last 5 games have gone over 144.

Comment: A [mre] of this problem would be nicer than a link to docs.google.com. Just because that is an external link which might fail in some future, ans then this whole question is pretty uninteresting for any future visitors of stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hI-b9LwFIXCvO8OyetgZUIimHBoUygTaNoWpSAHzUHU/edit#gid=572724986) you may test out:*

```js
=map(B3:B,AB3:AB,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(or(Σ="",Λ=""),,countif(chooserows(filter(DB!C:C+DB!E:E,(DB!B:B=Σ)+(DB!D:D=Σ)),sequence(5,1,-1,-1)),">"&Λ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the previous commenters formula works pretty well. I have one more formula that might work for you as well which I'll include below. Should work well for you as long as no score is over 9,999,999 which I don't expect will happen.

```
=COUNTIF(
ArrayFormula(VALUE(RIGHT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({
TEXT(ArrayFormula(IF((DB!B3:B=B3)+(DB!D3:D=B3),DB!A3:A,)),"YYYY/MM/DD")
&"~"&
TEXT(ArrayFormula(IF((DB!B3:B=B3)+(DB!D3:D=B3), DB!C3:C+DB!E3:E,)),"0000000")
},1,0),5,1),7)))
,">"&K3)
```

I also added a custom function to your copy sheet called GDD_SO_FUNCTION and applied it to AE4 which could simplify things for you. You'd just need to import the custom function onto your primary sheet if you'd like to use it. Here's what it looks like.

```
=GDD_SO_FUNCTION(B4,DB!B3:B,DB!C3:C,DB!D3:D,DB!E3:E,K4,DB!A3:A,5)
```

Comment: Please read: [How do I write a good answer?/Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Provide%20context%20for%20links). I think it asks you to provide the code for this custom function in the answer you gave here. Can/Will you add it ?